# Is there a decent diagram of packet flow for a modern era (2.6+) iptables setup?

Tags: linux, nat, iptables

I'm currently trying to debug a particularly hairy set of DNAT based iptables rules (the UDP reply never makes it back to the original requester) and I'm struggling to visualise the  packet flow through all the numerous tables involved. So far Google'ing has shown me old 2.4 based ipchains ones. The netfilter site has some good text docs but is short on diagrams and a number of the external links are now dead.

So is there a canonical diagram for iptables packet flow, preferably showing how NAT/Masqueraded packets are also dealt with?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg